# Metric Space Definition

Tags: metric-spaces, definition

From my book, the definition given is:

Given a set $X$, a function $d: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a metric on $X$ if for all $x,y \in X \dots$

Then a metric space is a set $X$ together with a metric $d$.

What exactly is meant by the $X \times X$ here?

Is it essentially a cross product between any two components of $X$, which can be any sort of space, e.g complex plane, $\mathbb{R}^2$ etc ?

Comment: It is a distance.  You need to compute the distance between *two* points, hence the $X\times X$ (meaning that the distance has two inputs).

Comment: Whoops, how obvious. -_-

Except then why is it mapped to $\mathbb{R}$, shouldn't it be mapped to $[0,\infty)$

Comment: One of the requirements on the metric, which are in your $\dots $ is that $d(x,y) \ge 0$, so it is mapped to $[0, \infty)$

Comment: Since $[0, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$, there is nothing wrong with listing $\mathbb{R}$ as the codomain.

Comment: You can view a function of two elements as a function of one element of the cross product of the domain with itself.  These would technically be different functions as they have different domains, but there is a clear correspondence between them.  My last comment, in using the notation $d(x,y)$, implied that $d$ took two elements of $X$ as arguments.  In fact it takes a single ordered pair, so it would be better to write $d((x,y))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the Cartesian product defined by $X \times Y = \{ (x,y) | x \in X \quad y \in Y \} $

So for example $\{ 1 , 2 \} \times \{3,4\} = \{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)\}$

Comment: This is the best explanation ever